# Syntax for referencing external sheets in JXLS template formula

Tags: java, excel, jxls

Jxls is a small Java library to make generation of Excel reports easy. Jxls uses a special markup in Excel templates to define output formatting and data layout.

I want to know how should I reference sheets of external files.

`$[VLOOKUP(G3,[book.xlsx]Sheet.A1:F10000,5,)]` gives me error.

Comment: Also JXLS has no "IFERROR" formula. What an annoying library!

Answer (score 0):

If you use jxls-2 you do not have to put a formula into $[].

You can just use regular Excel formulas.

Comment: I use it from within SaaS ERP system. So unfortunately I'm unable to update.